# Overriding config values in Nodeclipse

Tags: node.js, redis, nodeclipse

I use this command to run from the command line:

```
node app '--NODE_CONFIG={"redis":{"encryption":{"enabled":false}}}'
```

This overrides the config property stored as true to false.

in Nodeclipse I use this as the Program Argument:

```
'--NODE_CONFIG={"redis":{"encryption":{"enabled":false}}}'
```

When I run from Nodeclipse, the property is not overwritten.  I see this as the process that's run (ps -ef | grep node):

/usr/bin/node /home/dev/workspace/project/app.js '--NODE_CONFIG={"redis":{"encryption":{"enabled":false}}}'

That looks fine to me, but the property remains true in the application.  If I stop the Nodeclipse application and copy and paste the line above, the property is set to false.

I also tried copying this to the Node Arguments section in Nodeclipse but got an error.

Comment: Could you update with how exactly you configured Program Arguments and what error you got when passing as Node Arguments. It is also absolutely not clear in what module and in what time that parameter should be processed.